# Is there a workaround to the C# 28-time inline limit?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, .net-4.0

I am working on optimizing a physics simulation program using Red Gate's Performance Profiler. One part of the code dealing with collision detection had around 52 of the following little checks, dealing with cells in 26 directions in 3 dimensions, under two cases.

```
CollisionPrimitiveList cell = innerGrid[cellIndex + 1];
if (cell.Count > 0)
    contactsMade += collideWithCell(obj, cell, data, ref attemptedContacts);

cell = innerGrid[cellIndex + grid.XExtent];
if (cell.Count > 0)
    contactsMade += collideWithCell(obj, cell, data, ref attemptedContacts);

cell = innerGrid[cellIndex + grid.XzLayerSize];
if (cell.Count > 0)
    contactsMade += collideWithCell(obj, cell, data, ref attemptedContacts);
```

As an extremely tight loop of the program, all of this had to be in the same method, but I found that, suddenly, after I had extended the area from two dimensions to three dimensions (rising the count to 52 checks from 16), suddenly cell.Count was no longer being inlined, even though it is a simple getter.
`public int Count { get { return count; } }`
This caused a humongous performance hit, and it took me a considerable time to find that, when cell.Count appeared in the method 28 times or less, it was inlined every time, but once cell.Count appeared in the method 29 times or more, it was not inlined a single time (even though the vast majority of calls were from worst-case scenario parts of the code that were rarely executed.)

So back to my question, does anybody have any idea to get around this limit? I think the easy solution is just to make the count field internal and not private, but I would like a better solution than this, or at least just a better understanding of the situation. I wish this sort of thing would have been mentioned on Microsoft's Writing High-Performance Managed Applications page at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973858.aspx but sadly it is not (possibly because of how arbitrary the 28 count limit is?)

I am using .NET 4.0.

EDIT: It looks like I misinterpreted my little testing. I found that the failure to inline was caused not by the methods themselves being called some 28+ times, but because the the method they ought to be inlined into is "too long" by some standard. This still confuses me, because I don't see how a simple getter could be rationally not inlined (and performance is significantly better with them inlined as my profiler clearly shows me), but apparently the CLI JIT compiler is refusing to inline anything just because the method is already large (playing around with slight variations showed me that this limit is a code size (from idasm) of 1500, above which no inlining is done, even in the case of my getters, which some testing showed add no additional code overhead to be inlined).

Thank you.

Comment: If you really care about performance, you won't use getter-setter. They just get in the way.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like a register optimisation - perhaps disassembling the IL will give some hints?

Comment: Ron, I suppose that would do just fine for my needs, but I do also like having the protection that the getter gives me by not allowing write access (Count is actually the count of nodes in a linked list here, things could be really bad if that was accidentally changed). Jeremy, I may try looking at the IL, but I was under the impression that it wouldn't help because inlining is only done by the CLR JIT compiler. (I can only tell about the inlining thanks to my profiler)

Comment: If you are really doing hi-performance simulations, you probabaly want to code the key classes and computations in C++, compile them seperately and execute them as unmanaged code. Presumably this lets the (C++) compiler do global optimizations (and lets you hint more loudly ("inline") that the C# compiler cannot do.

Comment: Jeremy, although my ildasm skills are not the greatest, I notice no difference in the disassembly across the threshold. Ira, at least based on my profiling, I don't that such a whole scale switch to C++ would be much of a benefit. Where the C# compiler has been refusing to inline, I have just manually inlined myself, and then been able to do my own optimizations as well. My inner loops have exactly 0 memory allocations, so I think it would mostly be a pain to have to port over to C++. I guess it really seems that there really isn't much of a managed good practice way to get around this.

Comment: This is dangerous advice, but for experimental purposes, what difference does wrapping the core of the method in an unsafe block do ?

Comment: @Russ Fun idea, but sadly I didn't notice any difference from that.

Comment: Reading http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidnotario/archive/2004/11/01/250398.aspx gives me the idea that this method is hitting the O(n^2) vs O(n) choice of optimization algorithm. From the site: "If you have a limited time to find the solution, a good approach could be doing the optimal solution for small Ns, and fallback to the non optimal, but fast, solver for larger Ns." I'd suggest trying to split the method into 2 submethods and call them in succession - this may get you under the limits of the JIT.

Comment: For large N, it's best to choose a good algorithm (bearing in mind *all* constraints) over fiddling around with peephole optimizations.

Comment: @Stefan I thought about trying to split up the method into two sub-methods and to put the border-case code (literally, border of the grid) in a separate method, but I have cringed at this because of the large reuse of local variables, which would necessitate around 10 parameters to the second method, or having to recalculate them all. @Donal to the best of my ability and knowledge, I have been doing exactly this, and are only doing the nitpicking I am because my profiler has shown it to be very significant.

Comment: @Alk: Make the property getter public and the underlining member internal.  Then you're not allowing outside users to mess it up.

Comment: @Brian Yeah, for my case that seems to be the only real solution, so it is what I have done. It is still interesting to try to figure out why the JIT compiler inlines how it does, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it seems like one possible workaround is to have multiple properties that all return the same thing. Conceivably you could then get 28 inlines per property.

Note that the number of times a method is inlined most likely depends on the size of native code for that method (See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2008/08/19/to-inline-or-not-to-inline-that-is-the-question.aspx), the the number 28 is specific to that one property. A simple property would likely get inlined more times than a more complex method.

Comment: While I can't say you had the answer, I tried your idea of multiple properties that return the same thing and was surprised that it did not in fact cause inlining to happen, which lead me to realize it was the size of the parent method, which the number of calls I had roughly approximated, that was actually the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Straight off, this doesn't explain why 28 is the magic number, but I'm curious what would happen if you collate all your candidate CollisionListPrimitive instances into an array, and then call your "if count > 0" block within a loop of the array?

Is the cell.Count call then made inline again?

e.g.

```
CollisionPrimitiveList[] cells = new CollisionPrimitiveList {
    innerGrid[cellIndex + 1],
    innerGrid[cellIndex + grid.XExtent],
    innerGrid[cellIndex + grid.XzLayerSize]
    // and all the rest
};

// Loop over cells - for demo only. Use for loop or LINQ'ify if faster
foreach (CollisionPrimitiveList cell in cells) 
{
    if (cell.Count > 0)
        contactsMade += collideWithCell(obj, cell, data, ref attemptedContacts);  
}
```

I know performance is the issue, and you'll have overheads constructing the array and looping through it, but if cell.Count is inline again, might the performance still be better / good enough overall?

Comment: In light of what I have just discovered about it being parent method code size, this would undoubtedly reduce that enough to cause the inlining to happen again. OTOH, This would only work for part of the method, because many cells have to be range checked before they are tested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (though in no way positive) that this might have to do with the [enregistration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973858.aspx) issue mentioned -- it's possible that the CLR is allocating a new variable for each if statement, and that those are exceeding a total of 64 variables. Do you think this might be the case?

Comment: I tried to test this hypothesis by adding arbitrary if statements with the cells that might cause these supposed extra variable allocations, but through my testing, that made little difference, and rather whether the inlining occurred or not had to do with the code size. I'm sure it is the native size that makes the real difference, but the ildasm reported size had a threshold consistently around 1500 or 1501.

Comment: @Akh: Your statements were not optimized out altogether, right? Did they have some side effect? (Try conditionally incrementing a global variable.)

Comment: They weren't optimized out, and how predictable am I? --They were incrementing a variable (contactsMade) and making comparisons with cell.Count.

Comment: @Akh: Oh haha okay, I don't know then... that's funny though!